# Is it a good practice to have an intensive __init__ method in a python class?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I am new to python classes. I am writing a class that takes as an argument an id, but then it has to compute another attribute that depends on the id, and that computation can be intense.

My approach was to compute everything at the initialization phase, although it takes time, and to save time, keep everything that was previously computed in a pickled dictionary, as shown below.

```
import pickle

def intensecomputation(id):
    # Compute otherattr, based on id
    ...
    ...
    return(otherattr)

class myclass:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        # Need to compute self.otherattr that depends on self.id
        # Check if I have computed that already
        mydict = pickle.load( open( "mydict.p", "rb" ) )
        if self.id in mydict:
            self.otherattr = mydict[self.id]
        else:
            self.otherattr = intensecomputation(id)
            # Save for later
            mydict[self.id] = self.otherattr
            pickle.dump( mydict, open( "mydict.p", "wb" ) )

myobject = myclass(10)
# Wait some time here (unless the id 10 is already precalculated in the past and is in the pickled dictionary)
print(myobject.id)
print(myobject.otherattr)
```

Is what I'm doing a good practice? Is there any reason that `__init__` should not be complicated and intense? I was thinking that if this is the case, then I could implement `intensecomputation` as a method of myclass and call it to populate `self.otherattr`, like so:

```
myobject = myclass(10)
# myobject.otherattr is empty
print(myobject.id)
myobject.intensecomputation()
# Now myobject.otherattr is created
print(myobject.otherattr)
```

In any case, given my scenario, I would be grateful if one could explain to me the best practice to implement `myclass`.

Comment: It really depends on what that computation is and what your class represents. The key decision isn't really "do I do this computation in `__init__`"; decisions like "is this other thing part of what my object represents" and "should my object actually represent something else" are more important.

Comment: There's nothing inherently bad about having a computationally expensive `__init__`, though.

Comment: I personally, wouldn't put file i/o into `__init__ `and I would make `otherattr` a property probably, which is computed/read from file first time you access it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with an involved init method, especially if you are trying not follow RAII style, where the object construction is initialization which is in general a good practice.  This way you know the object is valid upon construction if thats important, as opposed to having potentially expensive operations carried out later when you don't expect them to be expensive.

The pickle idea is good however I would suggest that you make `mydict` a class variable if its something suitable for sharing between initializations or it will fall out of scope after the init call each time and `mydict.p` isn't changing. The only change I might make here is to make the initialization of yourself.otherattr a function.  and alter the structure so you always do the same last piece

```
#snippet in your init

if myclass.mydict.empty() :
  ## load from the pickle so its shared for all class instantiations OR perhaps pull this out and make it part of class's init. otherwise every construction is reloading the pickle which could be as costly or more costly then your calculation itself. (File IO is slow) 

do_dump = false # track whether I make changes that require a pickle dump update
if self.id !not in mydict:
  mydict[self.id] = intensecomputation(id) # calc and memoize at once
  do_dump = true;
  pass

# now this is universal
self.otherattr = mydict[self.id] 

#other stuff... which might also need to be pickled

#before end
#re-pickle if important; ensuring to do so potentially via a try catch finally wrapper.
```

The other possibility as mentioned is use a decorator around the getter for the otherattr member which returns or calcs and memoizes the result there when and if its used.  benefit will really come down to how data is used. if you are doing a bunch of batch processing later with many of `myclass` instances in some sort of pipeline it will perform much better if the values are ready to go so to speak so the instruction cache of calculating whatever pipeline you have can stay hot as opposed to missed branch prediction every several times where it has to break the pipeline and calculate this value.